# Increase the date and assign as a max in date field

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm using javascript to get the value of form input field with `getElementById("myTextInputID")`

How can I increase the date by 21 days (3 weeks) and assign this new date as a max in the date field with name `end_date` ?

What I have tried with `new Date()` and `addDays(21)` is not working for me.

````
<form action ="form_page.php" method="post">
      <div id="standardPanel">*Task / Person: <input type="text" name="product" required ></div>
      <div id="standardPanel">*Description: <input type="text" name="customer" required ></div>
      <div id="standardPanel">*Date: <input id="myTextInputID" type="date" name="manufacture_one" required ></div>
      <p class="flip" onclick="showEndDate()">Click to add End Date</p>
      <div id="panel">
        End Date: (holidays only) <input type="date" name="end_date">
      </div>
      <div><input id="submit" name="action" type="submit" value="submit"/></div>
</form>

    <script>
    function showEndDate() {
      var inputValue = document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value;
      if(inputValue != "") {
        document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        alert("Date cannot be blank");
      }
      var inputValue = new Date(document.getElementById("myTextInputID").value);
      inputValue.addDays(21);
      document.getElementsByName('end_date')[0].setAttribute("max", inputValue);
    }
    </script>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **addDays method doesn't exist**. You need to use the `setDate()` method.

```js
let dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
dateInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log("eventWorking");
  var inputValue = dateInput.value;
  var inputDate = new Date(inputValue);
  console.log(inputDate);
  // Adding 21 days using setDate
  inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 21);
  
  console.log(inputDate);
})
```

```html
Date: <input id="dateInput" type="date" name="manufacture_one" required >
```

**In summary** you can just replace the line `inputValue.addDays(21);` with `inputValue.setDate(inputValue.getDate() + 21);`

But avoid using the same var name two times in the same method ! As it will be bring you problems and it is easy to find two differents name

Answer (score 1):

You use the `setDate` method to add the desired amount of days to an existing date object and, for simplicity in outputting to the `end_date` field rather than simply use `value` you can use `valueAsDate` as below.

Incidentally `ID` attributes MUST be unique and in most cases are not really required as identification of DOM elements can be done in other ways such as `querySelector`. Also perhaps worth noting is that the use of `inline` event handlers is not considered best practise nowadays - externally registered event handlers are much cleaner '-)

```js
document.querySelector('p.flip').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  let manufacture_date=this.parentNode.querySelector('[name="manufacture_one"]');
  let end_date=this.parentNode.querySelector('[name="end_date"]');

  if( manufacture_date.value=='' ){
    alert('Date cannot be blank');
    return false;
  }
  
  let mdate=new Date( manufacture_date.value );
  let ndate=new Date( mdate.setDate( mdate.getDate() + 21 ) );
  
  end_date.valueAsDate=ndate;
});
```

```html
<form action="form_page.php" method="post">
  <div>*Task / Person: <input type="text" name="product" required /></div>
  <div>*Description: <input type="text" name="customer" required /></div>
  <div>*Date: <input type="date" name="manufacture_one" required /></div>

  <p class="flip">Click to add End Date</p>

  <div id="panel">End Date: (holidays only) <input type="date" name="end_date"></div>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Or, an alternative that uses a `change` event listener bound to the `manufacture_one` date input field so that the user does not need to click the "click here to..." link to calculate the new date.

```js
document.querySelector('[name="manufacture_one"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  if( this.value=='' ){
    alert('Date cannot be blank');
    return false;
  }
  
  let mdate=new Date( this.value );
  document.forms.dates.end_date.valueAsDate=new Date( mdate.setDate( mdate.getDate() + 21 ) );
});
```

```html
<form name='dates' action="form_page.php" method="post">
  <div>*Task / Person: <input type="text" name="product" required /></div>
  <div>*Description: <input type="text" name="customer" required /></div>
  <div>*Date: <input type="date" name="manufacture_one" required /></div>
  <div id="panel">End Date: (holidays only) <input type="date" name="end_date"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```